# Count Total Schedules at 30 minute intervals using Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a way to calculate how many people are available at every 30-minute interval in a day, based on their start time and end time,
But I can't add date condition to the formula (When Adding another condition to the below-mentioned formula I am getting #NA

I have tried below formulae 
=SUMPRODUCT(((--(C$2:C$1000="1/1/2019")*(A$2:A$1000<=D2)+(B$2:B$1000>D2)+(A$2:A$1000>B$2:B$1000)=2)+0))

```
+-------+-------+------------+
| Start |  End  |    Date    |
+-------+-------+------------+
| 17:30 | 02:30 | 02/01/2019 |
| 17:30 | 02:30 | 02/01/2019 |
| 17:30 | 02:30 | 02/01/2019 |
| 17:30 | 02:30 | 02/01/2019 |
| 17:30 | 02:30 | 01/01/2019 |
| 17:30 | 02:30 | 01/01/2019 |
| 16:00 | 01:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 16:00 | 01:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 16:00 | 01:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 02/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 02/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 02/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 02/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 02/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 02/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 00:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 15:00 | 22:00 | 01/01/2019 |
| 14:30 | 18:30 | 01/01/2019 |
| 14:30 | 18:30 | 01/01/2019 |
| 14:30 | 18:30 | 01/01/2019 |
| 14:30 | 18:30 | 01/01/2019 |
| 14:30 | 18:30 | 01/01/2019 |
| 14:30 | 18:30 | 01/01/2019 |
+-------+-------+------------+
```

[image: Output]

Comment: We don't know how is your data arranged, can you please specify or send screenshot ?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Now i have attached the data

Comment: What do you mean by "But I cant date condition to it"?

Comment: Does the date go with the start time or the end time?

Comment: No I have got the time separated from Date which is C Column

Comment: To Summarize My Problem                                                                              
 I'm trying to find a way to calculate how many people are available at every 30-minute interval in a day, based on their start time and end time, But I can't add date condition to the formula (When Adding another condition to the below-mentioned formula I am getting #NA

I have tried below formulae =SUMPRODUCT(((--(C$2:C$1000="1/1/2019")*(A$2:A$1000<=D2)+(B$2:B$1000>D2)+(A$2:A$1000>B$2:B$1000)=2)+0))

Comment: What I meant was, does the person in the first row start on 1/1/2019 and finish the next morning on 1/2/1019, or do they start on 12/31/2018 and finish on 1/1/2019 ?

Comment: So First Emp Starts the Shift at 5:30 PM (1/2/2019) and Ends Shift at 2:30 AM (1/3/2019)  Date Columns is the date when the agent start Date

Comment: Any Help would be Appreciated

Comment: I'll try and have a look tomorrow, which would be tomorrow evening I think for you.

Comment: can you share the working code before you " add date condition to the formula " .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Well here is my formula and results, totally different:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$28+$A$2:$A$28<=G$1+$F2)*($C$2:$C$28+$B$2:$B$28+($B$2:$B$28<$A$2:$A$28)>=G$1+$F2))
```

This is just comparing the start date + time to the given date + time, and the end date + time also to the given date + time. If the shift goes through midnight, a day is added to the end date.

I have sorted the data because it makes it much easier to check, and used 1 hour increments to test it:

[image]

It makes sense to me because (for example) nothing is happening on the first day until 15:00, but some of those people are still working at midnight so get counted in the following day.

Comment: Thank you Very Tom Sharpe This is what exactly I was looking , Its working fine for me